# .htaccess redirect based on language with wildcard

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this on .htaccess for browser redirect based on language, to avoid another php code.
What i want is if the user  enters www.example.com/ (wildcard after slash) the browser redirects to en.example.com/wildcard.

what i have so far is this for each language:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^en.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://en.example.com [R,L]
```

this works well but if i enter www.example.com/contact it will redirect to en.example.com and not ex.example.com/contact

can you see what's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture `.*` and pass that to the rewrite URL in the `RewriteRule` definition as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://en.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Reference document: [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)